# Force typescript to see difference between (AType = string) !== (BType = string)

Tags: typescript

My project has two user's id - my internal id(database uuid) and external service's id (google id).
User entity has these ids.

```
User {
  id: string;
  googleId: string;
}
```

But new collaborators don't know what id should be used and where this id should be used.
Let's assume i have method

```
getUser(id: string): Promise<User>
```

This method should receive user.id as argument.
TS allow me to call this method with user.id or with user.googleId.

What i want to is to say that i want to receive just user.id and nothing else. Because this method returns nothing if i pass user.googleId and this correct behaviour and wrong usage of method(new collaborators doesn't know that it should be user.id and this is not user.googleId).
What i want to have(i tried it but this didn't work)

```
userId = string;
googleId = string;
const getUser(id: userId) => this.userRepository.findOne(id)
getUser(user.id) // correct usage, ts error is absent
getUser(user.googleId) // wrong usage, ts error is present and tells that userId and googleId types are incompatible
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to define a custom type guard and checking the id for a pattern which reflects either one of them.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using what's called "opaque types". It's essentially creating a new type that's a string for all intents and purposes, except that it's only assignable to itself, so if you do `user.id = googleId` you'd get an error as they are different but `userOne.id = userTwo.id` works, since they are the same.

Comment: @VLAZ your solution works perfectly! Thank you! This is what i needed!!! Please, answer on this question so i can mark your answer as the correct one. And then you will have rewards from stackoverflow))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VLAZ sad - opaque types. This solved my problem.